# Tensorflow : tf.argmax and slicing

Tags: python, tensorflow, slice, argmax

I would like to design this loss function:

```
sum((y[argmax(y_)] - y_[argmax(y_)])²)
```

I don't find a way to do `y[argmax(y_)]`. I tried `y[k]`, `y[:,k]` and `y[None,k]` none of these work. This is my code :

```
    Na = 3
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2, Na]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([Na]))
    y = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3])
    k = tf.argmax(y_, 1)
    diff = y[k] - y_[k]
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(diff))
```

And the error:

```
  File "/home/ncarrara/phd/code/cython/robotnavigation/ftq/cftq19.py", line 156, in <module>
    diff = y[k] - y_[k]
  File "/home/ncarrara/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 499, in _SliceHelper
    name=name)
  File "/home/ncarrara/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 663, in strided_slice
    shrink_axis_mask=shrink_axis_mask)
  File "/home/ncarrara/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 3515, in strided_slice
    shrink_axis_mask=shrink_axis_mask, name=name)
  File "/home/ncarrara/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/ncarrara/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2508, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
  File "/home/ncarrara/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1873, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "/home/ncarrara/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1823, in call_with_requiring
    return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
  File "/home/ncarrara/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 610, in call_cpp_shape_fn
    debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
  File "/home/ncarrara/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 676, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [?,3], [1,?], [1,?], [1].
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can be done using [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd):

```
import tensorflow as tf

Na = 3
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2, Na]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([Na]))
y = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3])
k = tf.argmax(y_, 1)
# Make index tensor with row and column indices
num_examples = tf.cast(tf.shape(x)[0], dtype=k.dtype)
idx = tf.stack([tf.range(num_examples), k], axis=-1)
diff = tf.gather_nd(y, idx) - tf.gather_nd(y_, idx)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(diff))
```

Explanation:

In this case, the idea of `tf.gather_nd` is to make a matrix (a two-dimensional tensor) where each row contains the index of the row and column to have in the output. For example, if I have a matrix `a` containing:

```
| 1 2 3 |
| 4 5 6 |
| 7 8 9 |
```

And a matrix `i` containing:

```
| 1 2 |
| 0 1 |
| 2 2 |
| 1 0 |
```

Then the result of `tf.gather_nd(a, i)` would be the vector (one-dimensional tensor) containing:

```
| 6 |
| 2 |
| 9 |
| 4 |
```

In this case, the column indices are given by `tf.argmax` in `k`; it tells you, for every row, which is the column with the highest value. Now you just need to put the row index with each of these. The first element in `k` is the index of the max value column in row 0, the next element the one for row 1, and so on. `num_examples` is just the number of rows in `x` and `tf.range(num_examples)` gives you then a vector from 0 to the number of rows in `x` minus 1 (that is, all the sequence of row indices). Now you just need to put that together with `k`, which is what `tf.stack` does, and the result `idx` is the argument for `tf.gather_nd`.

Comment: Looks good but right now I'm not sure enough to validate your answer, thank you anyway !

Comment: @nicolascarrara I have added some explanations.