# Tensorflow: argmin/argmax, then slice

Tags: tensorflow

This is a follow up question to [Tensorflow : tf.argmax and slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45836241/tensorflow-tf-argmax-and-slicing), which is 5 years old and only applies in the case of 2D tensors.

I have a rank `D` tensor `x`, and I wish to compute the argmax/argmin over one of its axes, then slice the tensor using the argmin/argmax. Something like:

```
x_min_indices = tf.mathm.argmin(x, axis=3)  # choosing an arbitrary axis
x_min = x[x_min_indices]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Same basic idea as the original question you mentioned. Anytime you are trying to do fancy indexing from numpy, know that you are going to need tf.gather or tf.gather_nd.

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Can you provide specific inputs and expected output.

In particular, when you run tf.math.argmin(x, axis=3), your result is a rank D-1 tensor. What did you expect when you called x[x_min_indices]?

Comment: I upvoted your answer. To clarify, the result of argmin is indeed a rank D-1 tensor. When I call `x[x_min_indices]`, I would like to slice the elements along the axis I computed the argmin over. So for instance, if `x=[2, 1, 3]`, argmin would return `1` and then `x[x_min_indices]` would equal `1`. But this is the simple vector->scalar case. I want a generic solution for the rank D->rank D-1 case

Comment: I tried the solution in the previous post and received an error. I'm unsure whether the previous post's solution works unless the axis is the trailing axis

Comment: can you provide a numerical example of what you'd like with a rank 4 tensor?